# JavaFX - Is there a method to print one image multiple times using imageview?

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, tile, gridpane

Given the code below, i'm trying to print out a single image (stored in variable 'image') multiple times. Any suggestions as to how i'd go about doing this? Any information would be useful.

```
    Image image = new Image("tileset.png");
    ImageView tileset = new ImageView();
    tileset.setImage(image);

    Rectangle2D viewport1 = new Rectangle2D(0,16,16,16); //(selected pixels)
    tileset.setViewport(viewport1);
    int length = 40, width= 40;  // declare size of array (print 40x40)

    // loop through grid, fill every tile with image 'image'. 
    // currently only fills position (40,40) with the image. 
    for(int y = 0; y < length; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            GridPane.setConstraints(tileset,x,y);
        }
    }


    root.getChildren().add(tileset);
```

Comment: Create multiple `ImageView`s in the loop, each one using the same `Image`

Comment: I'm having difficulties doing so, could you give a suggestion as to what the loop needs to contain in order to produce multiple ImageView's? Would the ImageView data type need to be converted to an array? (also, thanks for the tip, at least i have somewhere to start at this point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `GridPane.setConstraints(tileset,x,y)` does not add a child to gridpane, it just sets the indices of child node. In order to add it to gridpane you should call `root.getChildren().add(tileset)` every time in the loop with a new `ImageView`.

```
Image image = new Image("tileset.png");

Rectangle2D viewport1 = new Rectangle2D(0,16,16,16); //(selected pixels)
int length = 40, width= 40;  // declare size of array (print 40x40)

// loop through grid, fill every tile with image 'image'. 
// currently only fills position (40,40) with the image. 
for(int y = 0; y < length; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        ImageView tileset = new ImageView(image);
        tileset.setViewport(viewport1);

        GridPane.setConstraints(tileset,x,y);
        root.getChildren().add(tileset);
    }
}
```